# Room database reset to default values which was set by prepopulating database when clearing app from background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have a database which is prepopulated with some tables which is working fine.
I have prepopulated my db. like this

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(
        get(),
        AppDatabase::class.java,
        APP_DATABASE
         )
        .createFromAsset("app.db")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
```

the problem I am facing is that. when user adds his own data it got inserted correctly and displayed on my screen.
when I move app to the background and remove it from there and reopen the application.
I don't se my data and only the default data is present there.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: same issue. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue - you just need to remove `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` from your code
finally your code should look like

```
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(
        context: Context
    ): AppDatabase {

        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                DATABASE_NAME
            )
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .createFromAsset("databases/yourdb.db")
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
 
            instance
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes exactly I solved it using the same thing.
but you shouldn't use allowMainThreadQueries() as it will perform operations on Main Thread.

Comment: @vivekpanchal but don't remove this line at all. if you will change db's version - you can use it to avoid migration writing. just uncomment it for first start with new version and comment again after it

Answer (score 0):

you should use Dao & annotation & ... to insert data to database.

you can use this for java
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#0

and this for kotlin
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0